# Finding work done by rotational force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque, angular-velocity

> A disk with a rotational inertia of 5.0 kg·m2 and a radius of 0.25 m
>   rotates on a fixed axis perpendicular to the disk and through its
>   center.  A force of 2.0 N is applied tangentially to the rim.  As the
>   disk turns through half a revolution, the work done by the force is:

This was another question on my test that I missed.  I didn't know where to get started.  I know the work done is the integral of the torque.  However, I don't know how to get a function that I can integrate from this example.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work is force over distance. What is force and over what distance does it apply?

Comment: Like I said in my comment I figured it out.  d can be found by using the radius*pi, and work is just W=Fd.  So I figured it out. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Think about what information is given in the problem that you can use to calculate the torque. (To say any more would be giving too much away)

Comment: Well what I just thought of is that the distance = R*pi.  From there I could use W=Fd and the answer would be `1.6`. However, tha doesn't sound like what you're trying to convey.

Comment: That is one way to do it.

Comment: Well since that looks like it's the correct answer, how would you go about it your way? I feel so dumb that I can't see how to calculate the torque from the information given.

Comment: What ways do you know of to calculate torque?

Comment: `Tnet = I a`, `Tnet = dl/dt`, `T= r x F`, `T=rFsin(theta)`.  Duh.  The last one? ;)  So once I have the torque, is that equivalent to the force on the object?

Comment: Torque is not the same thing as force, but there are similarities in the kinds of calculations you can do with it.